# A PHP script for MongoDB accent search needs to translate into JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, regex, node.js, mongodb

I found a PHP script that let to find text in some accent characters. My project is nodejs+mongodb so I tried to translate JavaScript but I couldn't be able to translate it at all. Since I don't know PHP very well, need some help to translate.

PHP Script source code is from http://tech.rgou.net/en/php/pesquisas-nao-sensiveis-ao-caso-e-acento-no-mongodb-e-php/

```
/**

* Description of StringUtil

*

* @author  Rafael Goulart

*/

class StringUtil {

const ACCENT_STRINGS = 'ŠŒŽšœžŸ¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËẼÌÍÎÏĨÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëẽìíîïĩðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ';

const NO_ACCENT_STRINGS = 'SOZsozYYuAAAAAAACEEEEEIIIIIDNOOOOOOUUUUYsaaaaaaaceeeeeiiiiionoooooouuuuyy';

/**

* Returns a string with accent to REGEX expression to find any combinations

* in accent insentive way

*

* @param string $text The text.

* @return string The REGEX text.

*/

static public function accentToRegex($text)

{

$from = str_split(utf8_decode(self::ACCENT_STRINGS));

$to   = str_split(strtolower(self::NO_ACCENT_STRINGS));

$text = utf8_decode($text);

$regex = array();

foreach ($to as $key => $value)

{

if (isset($regex[$value]))

{

$regex[$value] .= $from[$key];

} else {

$regex[$value] = $value;

}

}

foreach ($regex as $rg_key => $rg)

{

$text = preg_replace("/[$rg]/", "_{$rg_key}_", $text);

}

foreach ($regex as $rg_key => $rg)

{

$text = preg_replace("/_{$rg_key}_/", "[$rg]", $text);

}

return utf8_encode($text);

}

}
```

And here is my JavaScript code that need to be translate ... Any help would be appricated! Thanks.

```
function accentToRegex(word){

    var ACCENT_STRINGS = 'ŠŒŽšœžŸ¥µÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËẼÌÍÎÏĨÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝßàáâãäåæçèéêëẽìíîïĩðñòóôõöøùúûüýÿ';
    var NO_ACCENT_STRINGS = 'SOZsozYYuAAAAAAACEEEEEIIIIIDNOOOOOOUUUUYsaaaaaaaceeeeeiiiiionoooooouuuuyy';

    var from =  (ACCENT_STRINGS).split(decode_utf8(ACCENT_STRINGS));
    var to   = NO_ACCENT_STRINGS.split(NO_ACCENT_STRINGS.toLocaleLowerCase());

    var text = decode_utf8(word);
    var regex = new Array();

    for(value in to)
    {
        if (!regex[value])
        {
            regex[value] = from[value];
        } else {
            regex[value] = value;
        }
    }

    for (rg_key in regex)

    {
//          "$TESTONE $TESTONE".replace( new RegExp("\\$TESTONE","gm"),"foo")
//        text = preg_replace("/[$rg]/", "_{$rg_key}_", $text);
        text = text.replace(new RegExp(/[rg]/), new RegExp(_{rg_key}_)) ;

    }

    foreach (rg in regex)
  {

//        $text = preg_replace("/_{$rg_key}_/", "[$rg]", $text);
      text = text.replace(new RegExp(/[rg]/), new RegExp(_{rg_key}_)) ;

  }

    return encode_utf8(text); //Edited from $text to text

}

function encode_utf8(s) {
    return encodeURIComponent(s);
}

function decode_utf8(s) {
    return decodeURIComponent(s);
}
```

The error is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This

```
return encode_utf8($text);
```

should be

```
return encode_utf8(text); // no dollar-sign
```

but I haven't looked beyond this.

The JavaScript `RegExp` constructor expects a string, without delimiters. The delimiters are usually / but your expression is attempting to use underscores. JS only uses /.

```
new RegExp("hello")
new RegExp("[xy]")    // will look for either the character 'x' or 'y'
new RegExp(yourStringVariable)
new RegExp("[" + someVar + "]")
// .. will look for any of the letters in the variable someVar
```

These are the various ways you can use RegExp.

`for each` statements in JS are two separate words `for each (variable in object)`. But it is also deprecated and not widely supported. [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for_each...in)

Your second foreach also refers to the variable `rg_key` which doesn't have a meaningful value here.

I think there are a few other things that still require converting.

Comment: I edited but still getting error about RegExp. Please see the screenshot. Just edited above. Thanks.